# Visual Studio's useful plugins that can save hours of work, solve big problems

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005

As .NET developers most of us are using Visual Studio at work

Each now and then I found out that there is a very useful plugin just like http://vlh2005.codeplex.com/ that if I had from before could have saved me 10s of days of work well

What are the most used, most needed available plugins for Visual Studio ?

Things that can help to code better ?

Comment: Just checkout the top download on http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ and you have your answers....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For web developers: Web essentials, Elmah. Also ninject. I think it depepends on the project. But I would also like to hear about the general tools.

Answer (score 2):

Just one word - Resharper(backed with nice SSD and fat CPU)

Answer (score 1):

visual assist not free but very useful
chrome's developer tool

and codemap in vs

Answer (score 1):

You could explore [**VS Gallery - Products and Extensions for Visual Studio**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) website for the most popular, highest rated extensions for any VS version by any extension category (coding, performance, build, etc.), by any kind of cost (free, paid, trial).

Answer (score 1):

Nuget Package Manager is very nice too